# Batch convert svg to psd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm trying to use a bunch of svg icons on something I'm designing. Photoshop doesn't process svgs, apparently. I read Illustrator does and that I can just export it into psds. That much is managable but the problem is there are 300+ icons and I thought I'd just turn them all into psds in case I ever need them in the future.

How exactly do I do that? I'm using the CS5 suite.

Comment: You do realize that converting an svg to a psd is actually a step *backwards* in terms of quality, right? "For the future" would lean towards maintaining the svg format and using newer applications.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you want on you psds. Do you want a flattened pixel image of the svg or psd vector paths?

Comment: @Scott Why this should be "a step backwards"? Different types of medias support different file types - there are several reasons to rasterize a vector. The note should point out that an image can't edited like a vector.

Comment: Photoshop can't save [*true* vector content](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/9462/3270) so it's a step backwards.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use **[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)** and your **[command line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)** to convert it to a `png`, `jpg` or whatever. Following command **converts a single svg file** to a 1024x1024px png:

```
inkscape -z -e test.png -w 1024 -h 1024 test.svg
```

Inkscape has mighty command line options, with the `-z` argument you can run inkscape headless (without a gui). You only have to pass your disired image format, dimensions and image name. See the [docs](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/inkscape-man.html) for more information.

To Batch **process a folder of svgs** you can use a programming language of your choice and iterate through the files. I've used linux with **python 2.7+ (platform independent)** here:

```
import os # import os module
import subprocess # import subprocess module to call inkscape with python

# set the path to your svg folder
path = '/home/user/Desktop/svgs'   # linux or osx 
# path = r'c:\some\directory\svgs' # windows, the r is important
# path = 'c:/some/directory\svgs'  # windows (alternative)

# collect all svgs in this folder
svg_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.svg')] 

# iterate through the files
for i in svg_files:
    # setup correct filepath for inkscape
    file_path = os.path.join(path,i)
    # generate file the with a png extension
    png_path = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + '.png'
    # call inkscape with the correct arguments like in the example above 
    subprocess.call(['inkscape', '-z', '-e', png_path, '-w 1024', '-h 1024', file_path])
```

To convert a **png** or whatever to **psd file** use [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/). The command is simple:

```
convert test.png test.psd
```

See the [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) for more information. Batch process the **png files** to **psd files** via python again:

```
import os # import os module
import subprocess # import subprocess module

# set the path to your svg folder
path = '/home/user/Desktop/pngs'    # linux or osx
# path = r'c:\some\directory\pngs'  # windows, the r is important
# path = 'c:/some/directory\pngs'   # windows (alternative)

# collect all pngs in this folder
png_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.png')] 

# iterate through the files
for i in png_files:
    # setup correct filepath for pngs
    file_path = os.path.join(path,i)
    # generate file the with a psd extension
    psd_path = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + '.psd'
    # call imagemagick with the correct arguments
    subprocess.call(['convert', png_path, psd_path])
```

Generated files are working for me in **Photoshop CS4+**.

**Note:** *Converting the files in one iteration is also possible of course, but I thought for illustration purposes it's easier to split up the process.*

Comment: So all the shapes and layers in the svg will be joined into one rasterized psd layer?

Answer (score 1):

RabBits, I think right now no solution for SVG to Photoshop support, may be will come later. For the time solution you can open the file Illustrator-->File-->Export-->Format-->Photoshop (psd)-->OK.

[image]

Then you can open the file to Photoshop for edit.

Comment: Exactly. Record the above with an [Illustrator action](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/automation-actions.html) and you're good to go.